# Tool to analyse a logfile and alert when growing too fast?

Tags: 14.04, log, monitoring

I'm searching for a tool which can analyze logfiles and send notifications when a file gets, for example 10 entries in 1 minute. Also, it needs to provide a method to check if the file size is growing faster than, for example a week ago.

Does anyone know such a tool? Or do I have to write it on my own?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the application generating the log files and/or the log file names.

Comment: mostly it will be used for magento, but it would be nice if it would work for every logfile generated (like auth.log, systemlog or webserver logs)

Comment: Are you not concerned about the content of log file and only at the  rate at which new lines are added ? What kind of notification do you expect?

Comment: well, the content of the lines do matter. But mostly im interested in how many lines are added in a specific time range. 
as notification I expect something like:

unregular growth of (log file). please check if service has crashed. 

this would help me quite a lot. the content of the line of the last 10 Minutes could maybe send with the notification.

Maybe a ELK Stack in combination with a notificatiion/alerting mechanisim would be it.

Comment: You can summarize a log file by piping it to `cut "-d " -f5-  "$@" | sed -e 's/[0-9]/#/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn `, and figure out what to fix.

Comment: @waltinator Sadly not quite that what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you list down all log files you wanna monitor ?

Answer (score 0):

`logwatch` can be configured to do many things with log files:

```
trusty (8) logwatch.8.gz
Provided by: logwatch_7.4.0+svn20130529rev144-1ubuntu1_all 

NAME
       logwatch - system log analyzer and reporter

SYNOPSIS
       logwatch  [--detail  level  ]  [--logfile  log-file-group  ] [--service
       service-name ]  [--mailto  address  ]  [--archives]  [--range  range  ]
       [--debug   level  ]  [--filename  file-name  ]  [--logdir  directory  ]
       [--hostlimit hosts ] [--hostname  hostname  ]  [--html_wrap  number  of
       characters ] [--hostformat host based options ] [--output output-type ]
       [--format report format ]  [--encode  encoding  to  use  ]  [--numeric]
       [--version] [--help|--usage]

DESCRIPTION
       Logwatch  is  a customizable, pluggable log-monitoring system.  It will
       go through your logs for a given period of time and make  a  report  in
       the  areas  that  you  wish with the detail that you wish.  Logwatch is
       being used for Linux and many types of UNIX.
```